# Получение guid из .asset файла

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется файл с расширением .asset . Мне необходимо в Editor'е получить значение guid из m_Script.

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!114 &11400000
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 0
  m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: 3b5aa8beb48e4d04eb713804f2609273, type: 3}
  m_Name: testAsset
  m_EditorClassIdentifier:
```

Как можно это сделать? И предоставляет ли Unity вообще инструменты для подобных операций.

Comment: Юнити не предоставляет инструментов. Скорее всего придется самому писать что-то. Ведь даже YamlDotNet 
 который валяется на https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/36292  кривой и не может распарсить такой файл.... вообще в зависимости от задачи проще самому считать этот guid из файла. А вот если нужен некий ассоциативный массив - то надо постараться

Comment: Не стоит удалять вопрос. Если нашёл решение или найдешь в будущем - опубликуй как ответ. Если кто-то найдет сий вопрос и у него есть решение - он тоже напишет. Так что больше не удаляй ничего